# Samsung J5/S5 fingerprint sensor unresponsive at App start

Tags: android, react-native, samsung-mobile, fingerprint

I am developing an App using React Native. I am using fingerprint sensor to authenticate the user to make some operations. Sensors is working fine on all iOS and Android devices except for Samsung J5 and S5. The problem is that when app starts, the sensor become unresponsive for a while (about 25/35 seconds) and then it works fine. If the app is restarted the problem reappears. It seems that sensor requires some warming up time when app starts. We tried al lot of different React Native plugins to use fingerprint, but with all plugins the problem still remains. I checked very carefully if there are some background operations, but the app seems idling and making no tasks. Worst scenario is when a remote Push Notification arrives, the App is closed and user tap the notification popup to authorize an operation, the App starts and the user cannot authorize it for about 25/35 seconds. The fingerprint prompt appears suddenly without problem and the "cancel" button is responsive. If the user tap "cancel" button of the fingerprint popup and reopens it, nothing changes, sensor still remains unresponsive. After 25/35 seconds from app start, all further fingerprint operations works fine and responsive. Has someone any idea about the cause? How we can to troubleshoot this problem?